# How send old datas form fields across middleware in Express js

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have form with 3 fields: textfield1, textdield2 and input3. I render it.

```
router.get('/myform', function(req, res) {
  if(!req.session.passport){
    res.location('/');
    res.redirect('/');
  }
  res.render('user/myform', {
    title: 'Быстрая проверка',
    user: req.session.passport.user
  });
});
```

When i try to validate it i can catch some errors. That why i use express validator.

```
router.post('/myform', function(req, res) {
  var textfield1= req.body.textfield1;
  var textdield2 = req.body.textdield2;
  var input3 = req.body.input3;

  req.checkBody('textdield1','Cant be empty!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('textdield2 ','Cant be empty!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('input3','Cant be empty!').notEmpty();

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){
      var form = new Object();
      form.textfield1 = textfield1;
      form.textdield2 = textdield2;
      form.input3 = req.body.input3;
      res.render('user/myform',{
          errors: errors,
          title:"Errors here!",
          form: form
      });
  } else { ...
```

All works fine, but my middleware didnt want to works atall. For example this:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.locals.weauth = true;
    User.getUserById(req.session.passport.user, function(err, user) {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      if(!user.name) res.locals.username = user.username;
      else res.locals.username = user.name;
      res.locals.balance = user.balance;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    res.locals.weauth = null;
    next();
  }
});
```

What i do wrong and how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: What doesnt work exactly?. Note: you should use `app.use()` for a middleware, not `app.get('*')`

Comment: I changed `app.get()` to `app.use()` and all works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As said [Julien Klepatch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4789888/julien-klepatch), for using middleware i must use `app.use()`. When i changed it all problems was resolved.